# modifying css for modal dialogue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, css

I have a page which can be opened as a pop up page in sharepoint .Now when the page is opened as pop up I want some css to be modified.What is happening is that the code is able to successfully modify the label element but unable to modify the .ms-dlgTitle which is the window sharepoint opens which holds the page and is above the iFrame element holding the page.Can someone please tell me what I can do here.

```
<script src="/_layouts/1033/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function () 
 {if (window.location.search.match("[?&]IsDlg=1")) 
    {
        alert("doc is ready now"); 
        $('<style type="text/css">.ms-dlgTitle{ width: 200px; } #foo{background:black;                     }</style>').appendTo("head");}});

 function t(){  var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();options.url =           "http://sharepointhost:2266";options.height =      300;SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
             }
 </script>
<a class="s" onclick="javascript:t()">k</a> <label title="label1" id="foo">lbl</label>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do to `.ms-dlgTitleText`? In your code, you are applying CSS to `.ms-dlgTitle`, but doing nothing to `.ms-dlgTitleText`.

Comment: sorry was a mistake..changed it ..so basically say inside the page which opens up in the pop up I ant to modify the ms-dlgTitle width ..This is just an example I have to change the background image and all but just the width for making it easy to read right now..The problem is how do I access that elemnt from inside the page

Comment: Just to clarify again:

You have a page A with a link on it. That link opens a dialog of page B, on top of page A. You want to have CSS change on page A (e.g. background, dialog frame widths).

Comment: exactly..basicaly not everything just the dialogue box stuff like title border etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {           

        if (window.location.search.match("search=1")) {

            $("#dialogTitleSpan", parent.document).css({                    
                "line-height": "100%",
                "padding-left": "2px !important",                   
                "padding-top": "31px"
            });
        }
        });

</script>
```

The above is basically what was needed.It access the parent doc and change the css properties.